# Comparação de Cidades entre Trechos

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

Olá! Estou desenvolvendo um sistema que consiste em cadastro de trechos por bairro ou cidade. Neste caso que estou tomando como exemplo, inclui apenas dois trechos, como mostro na figura. Minha dúvida é, como comprar os trechos que estão vindo da array(), eu sei que no primeiro trecho as cidades são iguais, mas como comprar o segundo trecho, sendo que podem haver mais trechos?

O código que desenvolvi é o seguinte:

```
$intContagem = 1;
$intContagemArray = count($dados)-1;

for($idDados = 1; $idDados<=$intContagemArray; $idDados++){
    $idDadosAnt = 0;

    if($dados[0]['cidade'] == $dados[1]['cidade']){
        $sql = "SELECT $strSelect as vlrFrete FROM tabelafrete WHERE idSaida = ".$dados[$idDadosAnt]['bairro']." AND idDestino = ".$dados[$idDados]['bairro']."";   
    } else {
        $sql = "SELECT $strSelect as vlrFrete FROM tabelafretem WHERE idSaida = ".$dados[$idDadosAnt]['cidade']." AND idDestino = ".$dados[$idDados]['cidade']." AND referencia = 'C'";
    }

    $consulta = $this->db->query($sql)->result();
        foreach($consulta as $valor){
            $intContagem += $valor->vlrFrete;
        }
}
```

Trecho comparativo:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: vc precisa comparar o trecho zero com todos? ou precisa comparar o trecho atual com o proximo?

Comment: A comparação deve ser feita entre trechos. Trecho 1, verifico se a cidade é igual ao trecho 2, trecho 2, verifico se a cidade é igual ao trecho 3, e assim sucessivamente... Mas consegui a solução usando as variáveis que já tinhamos disponíveis. Postei a solução, veja se seria o ideal, por gentileza.

Comment: Foi isso ai que pensei mesmo, so fique em duvida se `$idDadosAnt` sempre deve ser zero.

Comment: Mas ainda está incorreto... Ele não deve ser sempre zero, tem que ir passando. de acordo com os trechos

Comment: não pode incrementar ele no if ou no else?

Comment: http://i.stack.imgur.com/OG2ti.png dá uma olhada no result